# Unity Photon timer synchronization

Tags: c#, unity3d, таймер, photoview

Всем, привет!.
Я в своей мультиплеерной игре использую Photon.
У меня в игре 2 команды А и Б. Также на карте есть зона (триггер), и если попасть на неё одной из команд, тогда таймер запускается с 10 секунд до 0, после чего некая функция в скрипте запускается. Этой зоне используется OnTriggerStay, то есть игроку, либо 2-ум игрокам из одной команды нужно на ней 10 секунд находится. 
Но при имлементации скрипта у меня возникли сложности:
Когда один игрок находится в зоне, то все ОК, таймер отсчитывается, функция запускается. НО, когда в этот же триггер заходит и 2ой игрок из той же команды (то есть в триггере сразу два игрока), то -> таймер в **два раза** быстрее проходит, и вместо 10 сек, по факту истекает 5 секунд и запускается необходимый скрипт.
Мне нужна помощь, как сделать чтоб при нахождении в тригере больше 1-ого игрока, таймер отсчитывался нормально, а не с увеличенной скоростью.

Вот обрывок скрипта:

```
private double _timeToNewScore = 10f;
private double _time;
private bool hasCapturedOne

private List <Health> team1players;

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{ 
 if (hasCapturedOne) 
 { 
   foreach (Health p in team1players) 
    { 
     ScorePointsFromPeriod(1); 
    }
 }
}

 private void ScorePointsFromPeriod(int team)
 {
         _time += Time.deltaTime; 
         if (_time >= _timeToNewScore)
         {
             DoSomething();
         }
 }
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Спасибо

Comment: This is StackOverflow in Russian. In case you want to contact English SO Community, ask your question at the main instance of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Otherwise please translate your question into Russian. Thank you!

Comment: Спасибо, перевел на русский. Не сразу понял, что здесь на русском :)

Comment: @ВеликийКомбинатор заново задайте этот вопрос

Comment: @nipercop, если вопрос закрыт - не нужно задавать его заново. Нужно устранить причины, после этого вопрос будет переоткрыт (как в данном случае).